# retriveing contacts in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-contacts

Hi i need to get contact details in edittext when i press a button.But i am getting it right when i have only one contact and it is showing an execption if it has more than one contact.Here is my code & i dont know what should i add to it.So help if anyone knows.Thanks in Adv.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
                       ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 



                  Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId , null, null); 
                  startManagingCursor(phones); 
                  while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                  e2.setText(phoneNumber);
                  } 

               //}

            Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null); 
            startManagingCursor(emails); 
            while (emails.moveToNext()) { 
               // This would allow you get several email addresses 
               String emailAddress = emails.getString( 
               emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)); 
               e3.setText(emailAddress);
            } 

            Cursor street = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI, 
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null); 
            startManagingCursor(street); 
            while (street.moveToNext()) { 
                String streetname=street.getString(street.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                e1.setText(streetname);
            }
            phones.close(); 
            emails.close(); 
            street.close();
            cursor.close();
```

Comment: what you want actually? explain more..

Comment: I need to get contact details of selected contact to the Edittext on pressing a button

Comment: if you have multiple contacts then put all in array and show that array in Edit text.

Answer (score 0):

you can visit [Contact Information](http://code.google.com/p/android-contacts-contract-example/) where all contacts and information is queried

Answer (score 0):

Change your while condition in `while(!cursor.isAfterLast())`.

Comment: I am getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException